# how to find and mark all links in the web page?

Tags: javascript, web, bho

I'm making an application which finds all links and buttons on the web page and
shows marks over the links and buttons (with any browser or custom application window).

Now, I'm trying to implement it with browser helper object(BHO)
and javascript. The BHO injects javascript code in the existing web site and the injected javascript finds the location of links and buttons and marks the links in the web page by analyzing DOM of the page.

However, it has many problems because there are lots of links that are coded by DHTML, javascript, flash and the like. What makes me difficult is that it is not easy to mark these links because it often moves and disappear after the page is completely loaded.

In particular, flash buttons cannot be accessed by HTML DOM, so I'm in trouble with finding such flash buttons with the above method. Therefore, it may be necessary for me to implement this application with different method or framework, but I can't find any other way to do. I think any method to find click-able object on the webpage of screen would be helpful to me. I hope you have some suggestions for me?

Comment: Please show the code you already have.

Answer (score 0):

To highlight all normal links on a site you can use this jQuery snippet:

```
$('a').css('color', '#F00');
```

There is no easy way to highlight flash links or links by `window.location` in JavaScript.